# How to include test case descriptions in lcov/genhtml code coverage output

Tags: code-coverage, testcase, lcov

I'm using lcov to generate code coverage reports for a C code base. I would like to integrate test descriptions into the final output (using lcov's gendesc utility.)

However, I have no clue on how to do that, and documentation on gendesc seems rather sparse (as far as the good old google has been able to tell me.)

The [gendesc info at LTP](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/gendesc.1.php) describes how to create the input test case description files (as expected by genhtml). And the [genhtml info](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/genhtml.1.php) provides `--show-descriptions`, and `--description-file` for inputting such test case description files.

However, I don't know how to reference the test cases so that they get included in the final report. genhtml sees them as *unused test cases* and thus keeps them out of the generated html output. I can use `--keep-descriptions`, but that doesn't tell me what test cases were run (obviously because I do not know how to make the reference from code to test description.)

So, how do we tell lcov/genhtml which tests were run in the final output? Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To associate a test case name with coverage data, specify that name while collecting coverage data using lcov's --test-name option:

```
lcov --capture --directory project-dir --output-file coverage.info --test-name "test01"
```

Then continue with the steps that you already mentioned, that is create a test case description file "tests.txt":

```
test01
    Some test
```

Convert it into the format expected by genhtml:

```
gendesc tests.txt --output-filename tests.desc
```

Finally specify the descriptions file to genhtml:

```
genhtml coverage.info --output-directory out --description-file tests.desc --show-details
```